# Why my question got deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Would like to know why [my question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/78169/41763) got deleted. Sure the question was closed, but it needed just 1 vote to get reopened. As can be read in the question, there are a similar question, but about Russia and that question got not deleted.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to have answered your own question in your question with accusations that several politicians have sent their children out of the country to avoid having to serve in the war. It seems very much like a push question designed to discredit members of Ukraine's government.

Comment: I just mentioned, that claims exist hat several politicians have sent their children out of the country to avoid having to serve in the war. Have never saied that claims are true. Wanted to know if that claims are based on any facts, or just false claims.

Comment: @convert And I explained that it was those claims that made the question look like you where pushing for an answer to discredit the Ukraine government.

Comment: I edited the question to explicitly show that it was not my intention to blame somebody.

Comment: @convert that doesn’t change how people looked at the question. Your repeated complaints about my answer is why people don’t normally explain things like this because they don’t want to deal with complaints about why they are wrong for saying why they took an action.